# Calling "application.processmessages" from unit - "application" is undeclared

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 7. I'm trying to add a procedure with a call to "application.processmessages" in a non-VCL unit.  I get the error "undeclared identifier: application".

How do I reference the TApplication class from a non-vcl unit? Where in the documentation is this described? It is hard to find due to the broad use of the term "application".

Comment: It's not hard to find if you know how to look. In a unit where it *does* compile, Ctrl+Click on the identifier. The IDE will take you to its declaration.

Comment: If you're calling `Application.ProcessMessages`, you're doing something wrong. Find a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "Non-VCL unit". If you are using Application, you are using the VCL - it's the glue that holds it together.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add Forms to the uses clause of your unit. Eg:

```
uses Forms;
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you do it then your unit becomes a VCL (-dependent) unit, are you sure that's the right way to go?

Application is a global variable in the Forms unit.